# Splitting up elements in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list looking like this:

```
[['m', '-407.45833,31.660713', 
'55.94048,-96.761902', 
'136.07143,106.589284', 'z'], 
['m', '-136.82738,39.976189', 
'35.52976,-120.196426', 
'43.089287,124.732141']]
```

and want it to look like this:

```
[['m', '-407.45833', '31.660713',
 '55.94048', '-96.761902',
 '136.07143', '106.589284', 'z'],
 ['m', '-136.82738', '39.976189', 
'35.52976', '-120.196426',
 '43.089287', '124.732141']]
```

Any suggestions?
Edit: This is what i tried so far.

```
list2=[]
for i in range (0, len(list)):
    list2.append(list[i].split())
list3=[]
for j in range(0, len(list2)):
    for i in range(0, len(list2[j])):
        list3.extend(list[j][i].split(',',1))
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is wrong in many ways

- In your first iteration, you have a list of lists so you cannot use `split` on a list.
- don't use `list` as a variable name
- don't iterate using `range` and indexes. Just use `for item in the_list:`

Me, I would skip all that and use list comprehensions:

Just split according to `,` and flatten the resulting lists using double list comprehension, wrapped in an outside list comprehension to iterate on the list of lists:

```
l = [['m', '-407.45833,31.660713', '55.94048,-96.761902', '136.07143,106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738,39.976189', '35.52976,-120.196426', '43.089287,124.732141']]

l = [[x for s in sl for x in s.split(',')] for sl in l]

print(l)
```

result:

```
[['m', '-407.45833', '31.660713', '55.94048', '-96.761902', '136.07143', '106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738', '39.976189', '35.52976', '-120.196426', '43.089287', '124.732141']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `str.split()` and `str.join()` functions:

```
l = [['m', '-407.45833,31.660713', '55.94048,-96.761902', '136.07143,106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738,39.976189', '35.52976,-120.196426', '43.089287,124.732141']]
result = [','.join(i).split(',') for i in l]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['m', '-407.45833', '31.660713', '55.94048', '-96.761902', '136.07143', '106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738', '39.976189', '35.52976', '-120.196426', '43.089287', '124.732141']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given :

```
>>> data = [['m', '-407.45833,31.660713', '55.94048,-96.761902', '136.07143,106.589284', 'z'], 
            ['m', '-136.82738,39.976189', '35.52976,-120.196426', '43.089287,124.732141']]
```

The key is to make a new *out_group* in a new *result* list.  To populate the *out_group*, loop over input *group*, then loop over its split fields.  That has the effect of "flattening" the data structure:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for group in data:
        out_group = []
        for element in group:
            for subelement in element.split(','):
                out_group.append(subelement)
        result.append(out_group)

>>> result
[['m', '-407.45833', '31.660713', '55.94048', '-96.761902', '136.07143', '106.589284', 'z'],
 ['m', '-136.82738', '39.976189', '35.52976', '-120.196426', '43.089287', '124.732141']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple imperative way of doing just this.

```
def split_up_elements(outer_list):
    results = []
    for inner_list in outer_list:
        temp_inner_list = []
        for item in inner_list:
            temp_inner_list.extend(item.split(','))
        results.append(temp_inner_list)
    return results
```

**Sample Output**

```
>>> outer_list = [['m', '-407.45833,31.660713', '55.94048,-96.761902', '136.07143,106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738,39.976189', '35.52976,-120.196426', '43.089287,124.732141']]
>>> split_up_elements(outer_list)
[['m', '-407.45833', '31.660713', '55.94048', '-96.761902', '136.07143', '106.589284', 'z'], ['m', '-136.82738', '39.976189', '35.52976', '-120.196426', '43.089287', '124.732141']]
```